# QtCreator: impossible to choose the CMake executable

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator

I'm on Debian 8 Jessie and I'm brand new to QtCreator.

It works well when I use it with QMake, but now I have to use CMake and I can't set the path to the "CMake executable" neither when I start a new project nor in the tools options.

When I choose the "CMake executable" (located at `/usr/bin/cmake` and works if I use it as a command in the terminal) then I can't click the `next` button since it is grayed.

Comment: Isn't the path `/usr/bin/cmake`? Unices are case sensitive.

Comment: Yes indeed, it is a typo (I choose the cmake executable with the GUI thus I can't set the wrong path).

Comment: I observe the same thing on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: I didn't manage to make it work directly in QtCreator and made it by hands...